# C++ Map get first element when second element is X

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

I have a C++ map called buttonValues as shown below.

```
map<int, int> buttonValues;
```

I put some data into my map as shown below.

```
buttonValues.insert(std::pair<int, int>(0, 1)); 
buttonValues.insert(std::pair<int, int>(1, 3)); 
buttonValues.insert(std::pair<int, int>(2, 0));
```

What I want to do is search for value 0 in the second column and if 0 is found in the second column, return the value in the first column. In this example, the value I would like to be returned is 2. So far I believe I can search for 0 in the second column with this:

```
buttonValues.find(0)->second
```

However, how do I get the value corresponding in the first column?

Thanks 
Calum

Comment: How should the algorithm behave when searching for `0` in `{{1,0}, {2,0}, {3,0}}`? When searching for `-1`?

Comment: Nothing would be found. This code will go into an if statement once this problem is solved so the if statement will just simply be passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`buttonValues.find(0)->second` will give you the value ("2nd column") corresponding to key `0`. In your example, it will return `1`. You need to iterate over the map and look for values `= 0` and then return the key:

```
for (const auto& keyval : buttonValues) // Look at each key-value pair
{
    if (keyval.second == 0) // If the value is 0...
    {
        return keyval.first; // ...return the first element in the pair
    }
}
```

You can put this in a function. Note that a map has unique keys but not necessarily unique values. So you should probably handle the case where you have multiple keys for which the value is `0`.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
for ( auto X : map_name )
  if ( X.second == 0 )
    return X.first;
```

`std::pair<>` holds values of first and second columns in your map. You can just iterate through all pairs and check second values for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually from performance's perspective, it is not suggested to search key by value from a map, the time complexity would be linear time `O(N)`. If you search value by key from a map, it would be 'O(logN)'. You can consider to build a reverse map or `multimap`, or even `unordered_map` / `unordered_multimap` depends on your use case.